# How to create ZigZag ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

[image]

Hello Sir,
I am new in development. I want to create above UI in flutter. Can anybody guide me how can I do that? thanks in advance.

I tried with [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) with no luck. :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.